# running cypress test cases with assertion expect(xhr.requestBody.test).to.not.exist, but eslint throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, cypress, eslint

```
 cy.wait("api").then((xhr: any) => {
      expect(xhr.method).to.eq("POST");
      expect(xhr.status).to.eq(200);
      expect(xhr.requestBody.test).to.not.exist;
    });
```

expect(xhr.requestBody.test).to.not.exist; this line throws eslint error as shown below:

```
error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verified at [tslint-playground](https://palantir.github.io/tslint-playground/).

Two alternates that pass the linter:

```js
expect(xhr.requestBody).to.not.have.property(test)

expect(xhr.requestBody.test).to.eq(undefined)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you have multiple options to solve this:

First and recommended option is to rewrite your assertion for example as follows:

```
const bodyContainsTest = xhr.requestBody.hasOwnProperty('test');
expect(bodyContainsTest).to.be.false;
```

Second option would be to simply disable that rule for the next line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
expect(xhr.requestBody.test).to.not.exist;
```

Another option would be to disable this rule globally for all Cypress test files in your `.eslintrc.json` if needed:

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "off",
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, the first option is still having the same issue  there is no differences between this way and expect(xhr.requestBody.test).to.not.exist; eslint will apply for the same rule on it. How about expect(xhr.requestBody.test).to.equal(undefined); BTW, other two options are working fine for sure.